# Write a simple interpreter, or find one I can use?

Tags: java, language-design, interpreter

I need a very simple interpreter that is written in Java.  The language is going to be simple.

I just need string operators, like "contains and equals".  I need logically AND, OR.  Along with parenthesis.

> "some string" CONTAINS "ring" AND
>   ("some string" EQUALS "input" OR "some other string"
>   CONTAINS "other")

This simply needs to evaluate to true or false.

Are there any open source intrepetors that would evaluate a language similar this?  Would I be better off just writing my own?

Comment: Do you mean an interpreter that interprets Java, or an interpreter written in Java?

Comment: sorry, written in Java.  I have edited.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be overkill, but you could use [JavaCC](https://javacc.dev.java.net/) to generate a parser for your language, then traverse the generated syntax tree for your input in order to evaluate the expression.

Answer (score 1):

[Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/intro.html) might be appropriate for what you're trying to accomplish. It offers dynamic execution of Java code that you can invoke from your app.

It's also open-source, so if you wanted to just see how it works you could do that too.